# how to store the printed output from a function as a vector in R?

Tags: r

I have the following column from a `dataframe`

```
df <- data.frame(
 crime = as.character(c(115400, 171200, 91124, 263899, 67601, 51322)),
 stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
```

I am using a function to extract the first two digits based on some condition as seen on the function below

```
for (i in df$crime){
  if (nchar(i)==6){
    print(substring(i,1,2))}
  else {print(substring(i,1,1))
  }
}
```

when I run this function I get the following output which is what I want

```
[1] "11"
[1] "17"
[1] "9"
[1] "26"
[1] "6"
[1] "5"
```

However, I want this to be saved as stand along vector. how do I do that?

Comment: @MrFlick these are actually codes that were in character format. Which is why I decided take that approach

Comment: Then in general that's why we ask you to include a `dput()` of your data rather than showing just the printed output. It's not possible to see how your data is stored just by looping at the printed output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution with `ifelse`+ `substring`

```
res <- with(df, substring(crime,1,ifelse(nchar(crime) == 6, 2, 1)))
```

such that

```
> res
[1] "11" "17" "9"  "26" "6"  "5"
```

Comment: Along a similar line: `with(df, substring(crime, 1, nchar(crime)-4))`

Answer (score 2):

`substr/substring` are vectorized, so we can use `ifelse`

```
v1 <- with(df1, ifelse(nchar(crime) == 6, substr(crime, 1, 2), substr(crime, 1, 1)))
v1
#[1] "11" "17" "9"  "26" "6"  "5"
```

---

In the OP's for loop, a `vector` can be initialized to store the output in each of the iterations

```
v1 <- character(nrow(df1))
for (i in seq_along(df1$crime)){
 if (nchar(df1$crime[i])==6){
      v1[i] <- substring(df1$crime[i],1,2)
   }  else {
      v1[i] <- substring(df1$crime[i],1,1)
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex :

```
output <- with(df, ifelse(nchar(crime) == 6, sub("(..).*", "\\1", crime), 
                                             sub("(.).*", "\\1", crime)))
output
#[1] "11" "17" "9"  "26" "6"  "5"
```

It becomes a little simpler with `str_extract` from `stringr`

```
with(df, ifelse(nchar(crime) == 6, stringr::str_extract(crime, ".."),
                                   stringr::str_extract(crime, ".")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine some situations where keeping the extracted codes *within* the original data frame is useful.

I'll use the `data.table` package as it's fast, which may be handy if your data is big.

```
library(data.table)

# convert your data.frame to data.table
setDT(df)

# filter the rows where crime length is 6,
# and assign the first two characters of
# it into a new variable "extracted".
# some rows now have NAs in the new
# field. The last [] prints it to screen.
df[nchar(crime) == 6, extracted := substring(crime, 1, 2)][]
```